# How to get Missing Elelement error if Element doesnot have value in xml

Tags: node.js, xml, xsd, libxml-js

I have tried to validate with xml against xsd using node module **libxmljs**(https://github.com/libxmljs/libxmljs/wiki#validating-against-xsd-schema) .So if element is mandatory in xsd but in xml element does not have any value ,it is empty then I should get error saying that Missing Element ,For example,

XSD:

```
<xsd:complexType name="ContractSummaryComplexType">
xsd:sequence
<xsd:element name="SvcAgreementID" type="xsd:string"/>
</xsd:sequence>
</xsd:complexType>
```

XML:

```
<SvcAgreementID></SvcAgreementID>
```

Please help me to do this.

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

Assiming MyContractSummaryComplex is an instance of ContractSummaryComplexType

The following should raise an error

```
<MyContractSummaryComplex>
</MyContractSummaryComplex>
```

The following are valid

```
<MyContractSummaryComplex>
    <SvcAgreementID></SvcAgreementID>
</MyContractSummaryComplex>

<MyContractSummaryComplex>
    <SvcAgreementID>ABC</SvcAgreementID>
</MyContractSummaryComplex>
```

Note `<SvcAgreementID></SvcAgreementID>` is saying here is an element `SvcAgreementID` with an empty string as its contents.

If you want to enforce a rule saying SvcAgreementID should contain at least 1 char then you need something like this

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8" ?>
<!--Created with Liquid Studio 2019 (https://www.liquid-technologies.com)-->
<xs:schema elementFormDefault="qualified" xmlns:xs="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema">
    <xs:complexType name="ContractSummaryComplexType">
        <xs:sequence>
            <xs:element name="SvcAgreementID">
                <xs:simpleType>
                    <xs:restriction base="xs:string">
                        <xs:minLength value="1" />
                    </xs:restriction>
                </xs:simpleType>
            </xs:element>
        </xs:sequence>
    </xs:complexType>
</xs:schema>
```